# How do you see what exceptions were raised in IIS 8.5?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web, iis-8.5

How do you see what exceptions were raised by your web application in IIS 8.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exceptions are available as `warning` event in the event log viewer under `Windows Logs\Application`

[image]